# copy files from Windows hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

My original drive was a 2.5" SATA III HDD. A few years ago I replaced it with a SSD. I accidentally deleted a lot of files recently.

I still have the old HDD and it will have some of my old photos. I see there are cable adapters to attach my old drive to my PC via USB.

If I get one of these cables and attach it will I see a "normal" drive with files or do I need to boot from that drive?

Comment: Yes. Unless the drive is hardware encrypted or something like that, the hard drive — if connected to that cable that then connects to your PC — will just show up as a normal hard drive and you can find the files you want that way.

Comment: The given answers are normally but not always correct.  Very occasionally the geometry (sector size I think) reported through a USB Interface does not match that reported when connected internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are talking about SATA to USB connectors, that will work and will show up as an external HDD with all the files that it contains, no need for anything else. External HDD are basically these drives (complete with SATA) *enclosed* in a plastic protection.